# User ID insert in SQL trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have been scanning the web looking for a answer, but most people answer using programming languages. I'm currently running a MySQL server and want to keep track of a `staff` table, when a staff members position is updated the trigger should insert values into the `staff_audit` table. Now the big question is how do I access the user id?

Code so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER staff_aft_update 
  AFTER UPDATE ON staff 
  FOR EACH ROW 
    INSERT INTO staff_audit 
      ( sau_st_staffno, sau_st_position_before, 
        sau_st_position_after, sau_user_id, ts) 
    VALUES 
      ( old.st_staffno, old.st_position, 
        new.st_position, userid);
```

where that `userid` is where i want the ID inserted. Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry meant into the 'staff_aft_update' table.

Comment: mysql, but I have access to a sql server as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the `userid` of the person performing the `UPDATE`?  If that `userid` is the MySQL username, just use `SUBSTRING_INDEX(USER(),'@',1)`; otherwise you will need to provide the `userid` from your application code.

Answer (score -1):

The following link should help you find the answer . This gives a list of informational functions in MySQL ..

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html

Indeed you need to use the information function USER() needs to pass user id from application code depending on the logic you need to implement .

For your requirement indeed you need to truncate everything starting from the '@' symbol as the format of the function user is user@localhost if you are using the Informational functions ....
hope this helpds

Comment: You can't use `CURRENT_USER()` for this purpose as the trigger will run under the account of its definer.  FYI, my answer performs the truncation you mention using `SUBSTRING_INDEX`.